# Watch doesn't deliver changes when using Sass and Tailwind

Tags: webpack, sass, tailwind-css, laravel-mix, postcss

- Laravel Mix Version: 6.0.39 (`npm list --depth=0`)
- Node Version (`node -v`): 17.0.1
- NPM Version (`npm -v`): 8.1.0
- OS: macOS Monterey v12.1

#### Description:

Hi, I'm using Laravel Mix with Tailwind 3.0.7.

This is mine `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');

mix
  .setPublicPath('dist')
  .browserSync({
    proxy: "http://localhost:10004",
    files: [
      'dist/**/**',
      'resources/**/**',
      '**/*.php',
    ],
  });

mix
  .js('resources/scripts/app.js', 'js')
  .js('resources/scripts/admin.js', 'js')
  .js('resources/scripts/tinymce-buttons.js', 'js')
  .autoload({
    jquery: [
      '$',
      'window.jQuery',
    ],
  });

mix
  .sass('resources/styles/app.scss', 'css')
  .sass('resources/styles/admin.scss', 'css')
  .sass('resources/styles/editor.scss', 'css');

mix
  .options({
    processCssUrls: false,
    postCss:        [
      tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
    ],
  });

mix
  .copy('resources/images', 'dist/images')
  .copy('resources/fonts', 'dist/fonts');

mix
  .version()
  .sourceMaps();
```

This is the content of `tailwind.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  mode:    'jit',
  content: [
    './**/*.php',
    './resources/scripts/*.js',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

#### Steps To Reproduce:

Everything works fine except watch. If I use commands `npx mix build` or `npx mix --production` it builds properly everything. But if I use `npx mix watch` it starts server with port 8000 and it reloads page properly after I make some change but build is not fresh. Not only that it doesn't compile changes on Tailwind classes but also other changes in my scss files. Basically it always delivers old files created after last `npx mix build`.

If I remove this part

```
    postCss:        [
      tailwindcss('./tailwind.config.js'),
    ],
```

then all changes in scss files are properly compiled when using `npx mix watch`.

Did anyone had some problems like these? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm experiencing something a bit different (compiler is on an infinite loop), but the only thing I've found is some documentation from Tailwind about Webpack not supporting fast-glob. From my tests, anything with a glob star `**` causes an infinite loop, but you seem to at least gotten past that hurdle. Any luck with your other issues?

Comment: Nothing yet. Though, I have gave up using Tailwind because of this issue. Actually that was the test if Tailwind can fit into my dev workflow. And it failed :) I don't even know if problem is in Tailwind itself or Webpack or Laravel Mix... I've skipped Tailwind. This should work out-of-the-box and I had no time to investigate this further.

Comment: After a full day of troubleshooting and experimenting, I agree. Seems like it's just a matter of time before these 2 very popular tools figure out a way to play nicely, but it's pretty frustrating in the meantime.